# Copy data from between two cell values, and paste copied data in new column in new worksheet using VBA (Excel)

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to copy all rows from between two cell values and paste the values in a new column in a new worksheet. Let's say my data is structured in one excel column as such:

```
x

1
2
3

y
x

4
5
6

y
```

So I want to copy the 123 and the 456, paste them in a new worksheet in columns A and B respectively, like so:

```
  A   B
1 1   4
2 2   5
3 3   6
```

The code that I have working copies the data just fine, but it only pastes them below each other. Is there any way to amend the following code to paste the copied data in a new column every time the loop runs through?

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

   Dim rownum As Long
   Dim colnum As Long
   Dim startrow As Long
   Dim endrow As Long
   Dim lastrow As Long
   rownum = 1
   colnum = 1
   lastrow = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row
   With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A" & lastrow)


   For rownum = 1 To lastrow
    Do
       If .Cells(rownum, 1).Value = "x" Then
          startrow = rownum
       End If

       rownum = rownum + 1


   If (rownum > lastrow) Then Exit For

   Loop Until .Cells(rownum, 1).Value = "y"
   endrow = rownum - 1
   rownum = rownum + 2

   Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(startrow & ":" & endrow).Copy


   Sheets("Sheet2").Select
   ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Select
   ActiveSheet.Paste


   Next rownum
   End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Seems to me your code will always paste everything in A1.

Comment: Not to mention that due to the `rownum = rownum + 1` and `rownum = rownum + 2` within a self incrementing loop, it won't see every `x` so often pastes the whole lot each time.

Comment: This code is slightly modified as the data set I'm using is not exactly as specified in the question; I had to do that for privacy reasons but probably should have been more clear in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a lot going on in that code that doesn't need to. Have a look at the below and see if you can follow what's happening:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Dim rownum As Long
    Dim colnum As Long
    Dim startrow As Long
    Dim endrow As Long
    Dim lastrow As Long

    colnum = 1 'start outputting to this column

    Dim rangetocopy As Range

    With Worksheets("Sheet1")
         lastrow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    End With

    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A" & lastrow)

        For rownum = 1 To lastrow

            If .Cells(rownum, 1).Value = "x" Then
                startrow = rownum
            End If

            If .Cells(rownum, 1).Value = "y" Or rownum = lastrow Then

                endrow = rownum
                Set rangetocopy = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & startrow & ":A" & endrow)
                rangetocopy.Copy Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(1, colnum)
                colnum = colnum + 1 ' set next output column
            End If

        Next rownum

    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: No, that wouldn't work @DavesExcel. rownum increments for every cell, whereas colnum increments only when a `y` is found.

Comment: This is really good, thank you. The only issue I'm coming across is that on some worksheets, there's no "y" rows at all. With the code I had in the question, it would pull rows between two "x" rows as well. Is there a way to amend this code to also do that? Like if there is no "y" to mark the end of the data being copied, could it come across another "x" and know when to stop?

Comment: See the edit. It'll now treat the last cell as a `Y`, regardless.

Answer (score 2):

you could use:

- `SpecialCells()` method of `Range` object to catch "numeric" values range
- `Areas` property of `Range` object to loop through each set of "numeric" range

as follows:

```
Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    With Worksheets("Sheet1")
        With .Range("A1", .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, xlNumbers)
            Dim area As Range
            For Each area In .Areas
                With Worksheets("Sheet2")
                    .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Offset(, 1).Resize(area.Rows.Count).Value = area.Value
                End With
            Next
        End With
    End With
    Worksheets("Sheet2").Columns(1).Delete
End Sub
```

---

to manage data of any format (not only "numeric") between "x"s or "x"s and "y"s, then use

- `AutoFilter()` method of `Range` object to filter data between "x"s or "x"s and "ys" "
- `SpecialCells()` method of `Range` object to catch not empty values range
- `Areas` property of `Range` object to loop through each set of "selected" range

as follows:

```
Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim area As Range

    With Worksheets("Sheet1")
        With .Range("A1", .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp))
            .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="<>x", Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:="<>y"
            With .Resize(.Rows.Count - 1).Offset(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants) '.Offset(-1)
                For Each area In .Areas
                    With Worksheets("Sheet2")
                        .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Offset(, 1).Resize(area.Rows.Count).Value = area.Value
                    End With
                Next

            End With
        End With
        .AutoFilterMode = False
    End With
    Worksheets("Sheet2").Columns(1).Delete
End Sub
```

Comment: That's pretty cool-- to my limited understanding though, this wouldn't work if the data is actually text? I used the numbers (1,2,3,4,5,6) to make the question easier to follow, but the actual data is alphanumeric.

Comment: @Tester_Y, yes, my first code works for "numeric" data, as per your example. See edit to manage alphanumeric data

Answer (score 1):

This type was already mentioned, but since I wrote it, I'll share it as well, using range areas.

This is also assuming layout is actual in the original question and that you are trying to extract a group of numbers.

```
Sub Button1_Click()
    Dim sh As Worksheet, ws As Worksheet
    Dim RangeArea As Range

    Set sh = Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set ws = Sheets("Sheet2")

    For Each RangeArea In sh.Columns("A").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, 1).Areas

        RangeArea.Copy ws.Cells(1, ws.Cells(1, ws.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column + 1)

    Next RangeArea

End Sub
```